# Unhandled Exception running eBay C# SDK on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, ebay-sdk

I downloaded the eBay SDK for use in an internal application we are developing. The catch is we are developing on Mono. When I run the eBay Hello World sample on .NET, it displays the following output:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Welcome to eBay SDK for .Net Sample +
+ - HelloWorld                        +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Begin to call eBay API, please wait ...
End to call eBay API, show call result:
eBay official Time: 11/27/2013 3:02:19 PM
```

When I run it with Mono, I get the following:

```
Unhandled Exception: eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.ApiException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.InvalidOperationException: WebServiceBindingAttribute is required on proxy class 'eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.eBayAPIInterfaceService2'.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapTypeStubInfo..ctor (System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalTypeInfo logicalTypeInfo) [0x00000]
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[],System.Exception&)
etc...etc...etc...
```

I found a workaround and will post it in an answer below.

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: I'm using 3.2.3, but according to the Novell Bugzilla report I posted in the answer below, this bug has existed since at least 2.10.x.

Comment: it's probable that this bug has existed from 0.1 version ;) please, always you ask a question about mono, specify the version you're using

Comment: Apologies... intended to but forgot in my excitement to post the answer. :) Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: hey, i got a similar error with mono, is there any way to get around it without recompiling by putting something in .config file ?

Comment: do you have any idea if your bug was ever followed up ?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. Still using my custom-compiled version. There has been no response to my bug report either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched Xamarin's Bugzilla and found nothing, but I found this relevant bug posted in Novell's old Mono Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693367

So I dug through the eBay SDK source and found that this was indeed the issue. `eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.eBayAPIInterfaceService2` inherits from `eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.eBayAPIInterfaceService`, which is decorated with a `System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute`.

So I changed `eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.eBayAPIInterfaceService2`, adding `[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "eBayAPISoapBinding", Namespace = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")]` so that it now looks like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using eBay.Service.Core.Soap;

namespace eBay.Service.Core.Sdk {
    /// <summary>
    /// Enhanced eBayAPIInterfaceService with GZIP compression support.
    /// </summary>
    [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "eBayAPISoapBinding", Namespace = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents")]
    internal class eBayAPIInterfaceService2 : eBayAPIInterfaceService {
        ...
    }
}
```

I followed the instructions in the eBay SDK for building from the sources and the problem was solved.

---

**Footnote**: Incidentally, if this is your first time using Mono to connect to an HTTPS web service, you will likely immediately run into another exception. That one will look like this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage:Process ()
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream handMsg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

For the solution to that, go here: http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Security

Comment: Reported the bug to Xamarin here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=16479