# Mono: Exception: WebServiceBindingAttribute is required on proxy class , but works in windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mono

When running program x under mono I get this error but it works in windows.

There are a few similar questions around [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246362/ebay-c-sharp-sdk-doesnt-work-on-mono) with this problem but more related to source code. Im hoping someone can suggest something i can try in a mono config file as I cant re/compile the program.

```
    Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: WebServiceBindingAttribute is required on proxy class 'NSClientCRM.DataCenterAwareNetSuiteService'.
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapTypeStubInfo..ctor (System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalTypeInfo logicalTypeInfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalTypeInfo.GetTypeStub (System.String protocolName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.TypeStubManager.GetTypeStub (System.Type t, System.String protocolName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at NSClientCRM.com.netsuite.webservices.NetSuiteService..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at NSClientCRM.DataCenterAwareNetSuiteService..ctor (System.String account) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) NSClientCRM.DataCenterAwareNetSuiteService:.ctor (string)
  at NSClientCRM.NSClientCRM..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at NSClientCRM.NSClientCRM.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: WebServiceBindingAttribute is required on proxy class 'NSClientCRM.DataCenterAwareNetSuiteService'.
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapTypeStubInfo..ctor (System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalTypeInfo logicalTypeInfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalTypeInfo.GetTypeStub (System.String protocolName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.TypeStubManager.GetTypeStub (System.Type t, System.String protocolName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at NSClientCRM.com.netsuite.webservices.NetSuiteService..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at NSClientCRM.DataCenterAwareNetSuiteService..ctor (System.String account) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) NSClientCRM.DataCenterAwareNetSuiteService:.ctor (string)
  at NSClientCRM.NSClientCRM..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at NSClientCRM.NSClientCRM.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```